# How to store foreign language characters in WordPress?

Tags: customization

I am building a membership site in WordPress. I have added a Notes functionality on my site where each unique user can login to the site and enter notes specific to each lesson/post. I am storing these notes in a custom table in db.

The user can enter the notes in any preferred language rather than just using English language for entering Notes. Now, the problem is notes are not getting stored properly in db if the user enters it in some other language. For example, if the user enters some characters in Russian language, it gets converted into this form

```
%u0414%u0440%u0435%u0432%u043D%u0435%u0440%u0443%u0441%u0441%u043A%u0438%u0439 %u043B%u0438%u0442%u0435%u0440%u0430%u0442%u0443%u0440%u043D%u044B%u0439 %u044F%u0437%u044B%u043A %u0438 %u0435%u0433%u043E
```

I am using the following query for inserting the data in the custom table:

```
<?php
    $wpdb->insert( 'wp_notes', array( 'userid' => $_POST['userid'], 'postid' => $_POST['postid'], 'note' => ''. stripslashes($_POST['notes']) .'', 'title' => ''. stripslashes($_POST['title']) .'' ),  array( '%d', '%d','%s','%s' ) );
?>
```

I am already using a meta tag for `charset utf-8` and my db is also set to `utf8_general_ci` Collation.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What happens in the DB if you enter russian text in a regular post/page?

Comment: If I enter the russian text as a comment or post, it is saved as it is in the DB.

Comment: And what if you do a `$wpdb->prepare()` before the `insert()`?

Comment: I tried using this query instead:  $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "INSERT INTO wp_notes (userid, postid, note, title) VALUES (%d, %d, %s, %s)", $_POST['userid'], $_POST['postid'], stripslashes($_POST['notes']), stripslashes($_POST['title']) ) );
but no luck :(

Comment: What happens if you don't use stripslashes?

Comment: I am using stripslashes only to get rid of any slashes the user enters. If I remove them, then it makes no difference.

Comment: Try to force your form to send data in UTF-8:`<form accept-charset="UTF-8">`. I think it's user's browser issue. Have you tried to replicate the problem in different browsers?

Comment: I have tried doing that also, but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: What happens if you run the text through `utf8_encode` before saving to the DB?

Comment: It might seems strange , but did you ensure your actual php file is `UTF-8 without BOM` ??